# LVDiff not working in Git

Tags: git, diff, labview

I'm trying to get lvdiff from meta-diff suite to work with Git.

My .gitconfig looks like this:

```
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/FIRST 2010 Beta/Java/LoganRover
[user]
    name = Tanner Smith
    email = tanner@notimportant.net
[merge "labview"]
    name = LabVIEW 3-Way Merge
    driver = 'C:/Program Files/National Instruments/Shared/LabVIEW Merge/LVMerge.exe' 'C:/Program Files/National Instruments/LabVIEW 8.6/LabVIEW.exe' %O %B %A %A
    recursive = binary
[diff "lvdiff"]
    #command = 'C:/Program Files/meta-diff suite/lvdiff.exe'
    external = C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/FIRST 2010 Beta/lvdiff.sh
[core]
    autocrlf = true
```

lvdiff.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

"C:/Program Files/meta-diff suite/lvdiff.exe" "$2" "%5" | cat
```

And my .gitattributes file looks like this:

```
#Use a cusstom driver to merge LabVIEW files
*.vi merge=labview

#Use lvdiff as the externel diff program for LabVIEW files
*.vi diff=lvdiff
```

But everytime I do a diff, all Git returns is:

```
diff --git a/Build DashBoard Data.vi b/Build DashBoard Data.vi
index fd50547..662237f 100644
Binary files a/Build DashBoard Data.vi and b/Build DeashBoard Data.vi differ
```

It is like it is not using it or even recognizing my changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Just completed my answer: if your file is a binary one, you need to defined a textual representation of it through textconv option.

Comment: @Tanner: if is an option you add to your custom diff in your `.gitattributes` file to refer to the program able to convert your binary file into a textual representation. See paragraph "Performing text diffs of binary files" of the `.gitattribute` man page.

Comment: But that would only be relevant to your case if the `.vi` files of yours are binary files.

Comment: And what would be the value of this? Without extreme knowledge of a binary file it makes no sense what the textual representation is.

Comment: @Ton: the value of this is the diff tool will not be called unless it is sure to be able to diff a *textual* representation (in order to build a patch). If it is a binary without any kind of textual conversion, the diff (custom or not) will simply return an simple message (stating the binary files are identical or different, and that is all)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have LabView, but there are a few bits of your configuration that are wrong.

1. The “external” setting under diff.lvdiff should be named “command”.
2. The “%” in your `lvdiff.sh` should probably be “$”.

On my machine (not Windows, no LabView), using `diff.lvdiff.command` and your `.gitattributes` is enough to let `git diff foo.vi` run the external diff driver (I even used a diff driver with a space in the pathname). The mis-configuration under `diff.lvdiff` is why you see the “binary file” message, it is the default diff message for files that appear to be binary. You may have been thinking of `diff.external`, which is related to `diff.foo.command`, but applies to ALL texual diffs, not just to the subset of paths with a `diff=foo` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your LVDiff has a space in it's path while you don't include the path inside quotes (like you do with the LabVIEW Merge).

LVDiff does not allow duplicate filenames, perhaps Git copies the remote file to your system and does not rename the file. Try editing the lvdiff.vi to rename one of the two files (I suggest to rename the second file.

See some instruction [here](http://www.labviewwiki.org/Hg#Setting_up_LVDiff)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size and nature of your v[irtual instrument (VI)](http://www.eelab.usyd.edu.au/labview/vi.html) files written in LabVIEW

- size: even if those files are text, but too small, they would be by default treated as binary
- nature: if they are binary, the default diff or merge tool would not work. (hence your custom diff set by `.gitattributes` might not kick in, I suppose.
  [`.gitattributes` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) assume a diff only for text files, where a patch can be generated. Maybe a **`textconv` config option** should be defined to perform a conversion of a `.vi` file into a textual representation.)

I had a similar problem with very small text file while trying to setup a custom merge in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755068/how-is-this-a-conflict/1755821#1755821).

Comment: Most of the vi files are around 10-40KB, though a few are around 5-8KB. The file in question is at least 24KB, so I don't see how that would be the problem.

Comment: For the record, .vi files *are* binary.

Answer (score 0):

I was successfull in doing a Merge with Mercurial by ommitting the reference to the actual LabVIEW path that should perform the Merge:

```
[merge-tools]
LVMerge.args = $base $other $local $output
LVMerge.executable = C:\Program Files\National Instruments\Shared\LabVIEW Merge\LVMerge.exe
LVMerge.gui = True
LVMerge.binary = True
[merge-patterns]
**.vi = LVMerge
**.ctl = LVMerge
**.lvclass = LVMerge
**.xctl = LVMerge
**.lvlib =LVMerge
```

Ton